# Shared Element Transition from fragment to fragment on new activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, material-design, android-transitions

I'm working on an app that currently uses a content transition on an `ImageView` from one fragment to another on the same activity. It is working fine however I have realised that my destination fragment needs to have it's own activity.

So let's say i have **Activity A** which contains **Fragment 1**
And I have **Activity B** which contains **Fragment 2**.
I need to perform a shared element transition from **Fragment 1** to **Fragment 2**.

Here is what i have done so far:
In the callback method from Fragment 1 to Activity A I'm passing the selected entity and also the imageview i want to transition from.

*Activity A*

```
 @Override
public void OnPhotographSelected(Photograph selectedPhoto,ImageView image) {
    Intent i= new Intent(this, PhotoDetailActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("photo_OBJ", selectedPhoto);
    i.putExtra("transitionName", image.getTransitionName());
    startActivity(i, ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this, image, "mainPhoto").toBundle());
}
```

*Activity B*

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_photo_detail);
    Photograph photoObj=new Photograph();
    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    String transitionName="";
    if(b!=null)
    {
        photoObj=(Photograph)b.getSerializable("photo_OBJ");
        transitionName=b.getString("transitionName");
    }
    PhotoDetailFragment pdf = PhotoDetailFragment.newInstance(photoObj);
    pdf.setSharedElementReturnTransition(TransitionInflater.from(this).inflateTransition(R.transition.change_image_transform));
    pdf.setSharedElementEnterTransition(TransitionInflater.from(this).inflateTransition(R.transition.change_image_transform));
    pdf.setImageTransitionId(transitionName);
    FragmentTransaction trans = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    trans.replace(R.id.photo_detail_content, pdf);
    trans.commit();
}
```

*Fragment 2*

```
 mainImg.setTransitionName(mImageTransitionID);
```

Activity Theme

```
 <item name="android:windowActivityTransitions">true</item>
```

I'm not seeing any content transition occur at runtime. As i mentioned earlier I had this transition working correctly from fragment to fragment within the same activity. 
Also worth noting is that Fragment 1 is a gridview so i have to maintain the transitionNames myself so they are all unique, that why you are seeing setTransitionName calls at runtime.

Any idea's why i'm not see the transition run?

Comment: My understanding of fragments is that they allow different displays within the same activity. Can you do transitions between fragments if they're not in the same activity?

Answer (score 3):

Try to use `postponeEnterTransition()` in your second activity inside `onCreate()` and `yourActivity.startPostponedEnterTransition()` in your fragment after you created your view in `onViewCreated()`.

If you're using **AppCompat** try `supportPostponeEnterTransition()` and `supportStartPostponedEnterTransition()` or `ActivityCompat.postponeEnterTransition(yourActivity)` and `ActivityCompat.startPostponedEnterTransition(yourActivity)`.

Credits to:
http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2015/03/activity-postponed-shared-element-transitions-part3b.html